# replacing a file with a symbolic link in a salt state

Tags: salt-stack

I'm new to salt-stack.

I'm trying to make sure a symbolic link exists.

```
/etc/localtime:
  file.symlink:
    - target: /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris
    - file.exists:
      - name: /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris
```

The result is as excepted when there's no existing `/etc/localtime`, or when `/etc/localtime` is already a symlink. But it fails when `/etc/localtime` is a regular file :

```
----------
State: - file
Name:      /etc/localtime
Function:  symlink
    Result:    False
    Comment:   File exists where the symlink /etc/localtime should be
    Changes:
```

I can't figure how to code the state so the file is deleted before the link creation. Any clue ?

Cheers,
Pierre

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `force=True`

```
/etc/locatime:
  file.symlink:
    - target: /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris
    - force: True
    # Note: file.exists is not valid here and can be removed
    # file.exists:
    #  - name: /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris
```

From [the documentation](http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.symlink):

> If the target of the symlink exists and is not a symlink and
>   force is set to False, the state will fail. If force is set to True,
>   the file or directory in the way of the symlink file will be deleted
>   to make room for the symlink, unless backupname is set, when it will
>   be renamed

Comment: I don't think "file.exists" is doing anything in this example. It is just being ignored because it's not a valid option to "file.symlink"

Comment: Hrm.  @Pierre I've removed the last two lines, can you confirm it still works?

Comment: @Dan-Garthwaite : Yes indeed. But the link is created even if the target does not exists !
So I guess something like this should be added elsewhere :
/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris:
  file.exists